# Как запретить прокрутку JavaFX ScrollPane?

Tags: java, javafx

Имеется следующая структура элементов на окне JFrame:
[image]

На JFrame расположена JPanel с JScrollPane. На этой панели располагается некое множество панелей со ScrollPane и WebView JavaFX. При этом каждому скролу заданы параметры: `scrollPane.setHbarPolicy(ScrollBarPolicy.NEVER); scrollPane.setVbarPolicy(ScrollBarPolicy.NEVER);`, скрывающие отображение элементов перемещения. Мне необходимо полностью запретить скроллинг на элементах ScrollPane.
Пробовал варианты: `scrollPane.setVmax(0); scrollPane.setFitToWidth(true); scrollPane.setFitToHeight(true); scrollPane.setDisable(false);`
Проблема заключается в том, что ScrollPane и WebView мешают спокойно скролить джавовский JScrollPane, потому как если курсор наведен на них, то прокрутка JScrollPane не работает

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;

public class basic {
    public static void main(String Args[]) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        frame.setSize(800, 500);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        
        GridBagLayout gblClipboard = new GridBagLayout();
        GridBagConstraints gbCClipboard = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbCClipboard.gridx = 0;
        gbCClipboard.weightx = 1;
        gbCClipboard.weighty = 0;
        gbCClipboard.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbCClipboard.insets = new Insets(4, 0, 24, 0);
        
        JPanel ClipboardContent = new JPanel();
        ClipboardContent.setLayout(gblClipboard);
        
        JScrollPane scrollClipboard = new JScrollPane();
        scrollClipboard.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        scrollClipboard.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        scrollClipboard.getVerticalScrollBar().setUnitIncrement(16);
        scrollClipboard.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 0));
        scrollClipboard.setOpaque(true);
        scrollClipboard.setViewportView(ClipboardContent);
        frame.add(scrollClipboard, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        for(int k = 0; k < 16; k++) {
            gbCClipboard.gridy = k;
            JPanel PANEL = createRecordPanel();
            gblClipboard.setConstraints(PANEL, gbCClipboard);
            ClipboardContent.add(PANEL);
        }
    }

    private static JPanel createRecordPanel() {
        JPanel PANEL = new JPanel();
        PANEL.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(0, 70));
        PANEL.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JFXPanel FXPANEL = create("Если навести курсор на данную область с JFXPanel и ScrollPane,"
                + "то прокрутка колесиком мыши работать не будет. На провежутках между панелями прокрутка работет");
        PANEL.add(FXPANEL, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        return PANEL;
    }
    //off
    static JFXPanel create(String dataText) {
        JFXPanel FXPANEL = new JFXPanel();
        Platform.setImplicitExit(false);
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            WebView webView = new WebView();
            webView.setContextMenuEnabled(false);
            
            WebEngine webEngine = webView.getEngine();
            webEngine.loadContent(dataText, "text/html");
            
            ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane();
            scrollPane.fitToWidthProperty().set(true);
            scrollPane.setHbarPolicy(ScrollBarPolicy.NEVER);
            scrollPane.setVbarPolicy(ScrollBarPolicy.NEVER);
            scrollPane.setContent(webView);
            
            FXPANEL.setScene(new Scene(scrollPane));
        });
        return FXPANEL;
    }
}
```

Comment: а зачем вы добавили скрол на WebView, у него же есть свой

Comment: Мне не удалось отключить отображение полос прокрутки на скроле WebView, поэтому я добавил его на отдельный скролл и решил манипулировать с ним.

Comment: Это наверняка можно решить через css

Comment: и JScrollPane относится к Swing, вы пытаетесь несколько технологий совместить. Возможно из за этого у вас проблемы

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38540635/how-to-disable-down-scrolling-in-scrollpane-in-javafx

Comment: Решил проверить, что если вместо скролла с webview поместить на панели JFXPanel. Результат тот же - JScrollPane не прокручивается, пока курсор находится на панели JavaFX. Получается, что проблема действительно в совмещении технологий

Comment: Полноценно описывая ситуацию: изначально приложение писал на чистой Джаве. Потом оказалось, что JEditorPane нормально не поддерживает языки форматированного текста/контента, что изначально и нужно было. Вследствие этого я прибегнул к варианту "прикрутить" WebView на панели, изображенные выше. И вот я застрял на скроллинге, что оказывается всё это дело друг с другом не дружит. И даже если там будет FXпанель, то скроллинг JScrollPane работать не будет, когда курсор будет наведен на нее

Comment: В голову только всякие костыли лезут ) Это нехорошо. А зачем вам WebView если не секрет ?

Comment: scrollPane.setDisable(false) - а ещё здесь вы наоборот говорите программе, скролпейн выключен?(нет)  --- > попробуйте туда положить true

Comment: WebView отлично отображает контент HTML/CSS, что собственно мне и нужно. Делаю менеджер буфера обмена. Каждая панель, расположенная на JScrollpane  должна содержать превьюшку перехваченного ранее контента, в числе которого text/html или text/plain.

Comment: Внедрение JavaFX с WebView в проект является вынужденной мерой, т.к. базовый элемент джавы - JEditorPane, плохо работает с HTML/CSS. Из альтернатив JavaFX нагуглил только JxBrowser, но у него есть приколы с лицензированием.

Comment: Насчет scrollPane.setDisable(false) - это вы верно подметили. Я исправлял false на true. Решением проблемы со скроллингом это не решило(

Comment: Попробуйте приложить минимально воспроизводимый пример, без внутренней логики, где работает чисто фронт. Я постараюсь вам помочь.

Comment: А так же прошу прописать под нужным Node элементом //off (который должен быть отключен)

Comment: Приложил к вопросу пример. Буду очень благодарен даже за попытку)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обратите внимание на входящие параметры, вам придется передать ссылку на ваш главный
jScrollPane, надеюсь я всё правильно понял ( переделываю ответ во второй раз :D )  Теперь всё прокручивается вверх и вниз. Изврат конечно... ) Что касается кода, мы передаем входящую дельту скрола из webView в главный jScrollPane, теоретически, скролл пейн от JFX уже даже не нужен, но пробовать я не стал.

```
 static JFXPanel create(String dataText,JScrollPane jScrollPane) {
                JFXPanel FXPANEL = new JFXPanel();
                Platform.setImplicitExit(false);
                Platform.runLater(() -> {
                    WebView webView = new WebView();
                    webView.setContextMenuEnabled(false);
        
                    WebEngine webEngine = webView.getEngine();
                    webEngine.loadContent(dataText, "text/html");
        
                    ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane();
                    scrollPane.fitToWidthProperty().set(true);
        
                    webView.setOnScroll(new EventHandler<ScrollEvent>() {
                        @Override
                        public void handle(ScrollEvent event) {
                            int y = (int) event.getDeltaY();
                            System.out.println(y);
                            if(y<0){
                                // reverse to DOWN
                                int y1 = jScrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().getValue();
                                jScrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setValue(y1+Math.abs(y));
                            }
        
                            if(y>0){
                                // reverse to UP
                                int y1 = jScrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().getValue();
                                jScrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setValue(y1-y-y);
                            }
        
                        }
                    });
                    scrollPane.setContent(webView);
                    FXPANEL.setScene(new Scene(scrollPane));
        
                });
                return FXPANEL;
            }
```

frame.setVisible(true); должен быть после цикла

Comment: О боже, как это прекрасно! Спасибо большое!)) Насчет изврата согласен, но прикольно)

Comment: Спасибо за ваш голос